# Trackpad/Cursor remains pressed and invisible - Dell i7559 - 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, suspend, touchpad, xinput

Suspending my laptop and opening it up later leaves my mouse in a perpetual click. I solve this issue by going to my settings and disabling/enabling the track pad (this usually solves it for my session).

However, this bug is occasionally present on the lock screen where I am unable to hit a key and remove the lock screen due to the mouse dragging it. I've found that toggling between tty1 and tty2 a few times lets me type on the lock screen and sign in. However, this doesn't fix my cursor.

Currently, my cursor is only visible on Ubuntu's top bar and performs its left click if I right click. When in plain view, moving the cursor anywhere else on screen makes it invisible and unresponsive to clicks. When opening the Activity overview, my mouse is visible and I can right click to select a window.

I've tried disabling my trackpad with xinput and I have confirmed this issue persists with a physical mouse plugged in as well. 
I am on a Dell Inspiron 7559 running Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks in advance.